# Source Control for iWork Files

Tags: icloud, finder, applescript, iwork

**Bottom Line** - Source Control for iWork files in organised folder structure.

**Background** - 
Our work has moved to iWork as the primary office suite. And one of my irks is that we have way too many emails with files as attachments flying back and forth.

I tend to download the attachments and put into the respective folders on my local drive for reference. For example, my Documents folder has multiple folders with project names as folder names and holds files inside.

**Solution vision** -

1. Every time I download an attachment, rename the attachment with the date as prefix - I can solve this using Hazel, kindof.
2. If the downloaded item is edited, create a copy of the old document and rename the new document with newly edited date - a little tricky.

OR

A local repository which does source control for the Mac, as I can't use third party cloud services like Dropbox or Google Drive or iCloud.

**Tools available** - Applescript, Hazel, Alfred, Better Touch Tool. Can buy new tools if needed.

Comment: Why can't you use third party cloud services? Maybe setting up owncloud on your own server would be an option?

Comment: Work policy do not let me put files on the cloud